# c# How can I make the listview columns occupy the entire window when I maximize it?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Hi I need to adjust the columns header such that they occupy the entire window when it is maximized.

The expected output are the listview columns ocupping the entire window but the real output are the columns don't ocuppy the entire window, otherwise the columns are ocupping a part of the window when it's maximized.

This is the class when I declare the methods are initializing and resizing the listview with their respective columns (these are not ocupping the entire window when I have it maximized.

```
public Takenshows()
{
InitializeComponent();
lvwColumnSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = lvwColumnSorter;
listView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill; //The table occupies the entire width of the window when the window is maximized.
}

//this is a helper method where we REFIT the sampler table by maximizing it
private void SizeLastColumn(System.Windows.Forms.ListView lv)
{
lv.Columns[lv.Columns.Count - 1].Width = -2;
lv.Columns[lv.Columns.Count - 1].AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None);
lv.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
lv.Alignment = ListViewAlignment.SnapToGrid;
}

//A method that allows you to wrap the table by calling the helper method that wraps the table when the window is maximized.
private void listView1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
SizeLastColumn((System.Windows.Forms.ListView)sender);
}

private void Takenshows_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// INITIALIZE the table

listView1.View = View.Details;
SizeLastColumn(listView1);
}
```

And this is a part from the code I have the designer of Takenshows.cs with the listview and their respective columns header.

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;
private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnordnum;
private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columndatetimeshow;
private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnvalues;
private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columntestnumber;

this.listView1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ListViewAlignment.SnapToGrid;
this.listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
this.listView1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top;
this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.columnordnum,
        this.columndatetimeshow,
        this.columnvalues,
        this.columntestnumber});
this.listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
this.listView1.HideSelection = false;
this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 4);
this.listView1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
this.listView1.MultiSelect = false;
this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1064, 559);
this.listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
this.listView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.listView1.TabIndex = 1;
this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
this.listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += new 
System.EventHandler(this.listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
// 
// columnordnum
// 
this.columnordnum.Text = "Order number";
this.columnordnum.Width = 115;
this.columnordnum.AutoResize(System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None);
// 
// columndatetimeshow
// 
this.columndatetimeshow.Text = "datetime show";
this.columndatetimeshow.Width = 140;
this.columndatetimeshow.AutoResize(System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None);
// 
// columnvalues
// 
this.columnvalues.Text = "values";
this.columnvalues.Width = 420;
this.columnvalues.AutoResize(System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None);
// 
// columntestnumber
// 
this.columntestnumber.Text = "test number";
this.columntestnumber.Width = 105;
this.columntestnumber.AutoResize(System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None);
```

I should rendering the listview such that the columns of the listview occupy the entire window when it's maximizing.

Is there any way can I solve this issue?

Comment: I don't see any piece of code that's subscribing to the `Resize` event of the ListView, only `SelectedIndexChanged`, in the Designer file -- In `SizeLastColumn()` you should just set the *magic number*, `lv.Columns[lv.Columns.Count - 1].Width = -2;`, the rest is useless

Comment: After have spent hours resizing the listview and columns to fit it, I used lv.Columns[lv.Columns.Count - 1].Width = -2; in my SizeLastColumn method and I setted the listview Anchor (only top and bottom) in the designer. The real output when I maximized the window, was the listview on the center with the columns automatically resized, but my expected output was that the columns of my listview occupy the entire window when it was maximized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the designer view, click on the ListView Tasks arrow (top right corner of the listview) and select "Dock in Parent Container".

Answer (score 1):

Your objective is to scale the `ListView` columns to fill the entire width of the main window when it's maximized (or generally resized). Assuming that the `ListView` is anchored, subscribing the the event fired by the `ListView` when it resizes will allow you to recalculate proportional (or custom) widths based on the new width of the window. For example:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        autoScaleColumns();
        listView.Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xF;
        listView.SizeChanged += (sender, e) => autoScaleColumns();
    }
    private void autoScaleColumns()
    {
        var proportional = listView.ClientRectangle.Width / listView.Columns.Count;
        foreach (ColumnHeader column in listView.Columns)
        {
            column.Width = proportional;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I would also encourage you to look into the alternative of using `DataGridView` which has built-in AutoSize properties that are much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is on Form Resize. This resizes all columns as well as resizes the very last column to maximize the rest of the ListView.

```
if (MyListView.Columns.Count > 0) {                     
    MyListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
    MyListView.AutoResizeColumn(lv.Columns.Count - 1, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
}
```